# Как правильно запрограммировать мнимую единицу С++

Tags: c++

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пытаюсь запрограммировать данное выражение. Как правильно запрограммировать мнимую единицу. И можете проверить правильность всего остального.

```
double Ez11(double z, double a, double l1, double lambda) {
    double R0 = sqrt(a * a + z * z);
    double R1 = sqrt(a * a + (z - l1) * (z - l1));
    double R2 = sqrt(a * a + (z + l1) * (z + l1));
    double k = 2 * M_PI / lambda;
    double W = 120 * M_PI;
    double i = 0;
    double Ez=-i*W/(4*M_PI*sin(k*l1))*(exp(-i*k*R1)/R1+exp(-i*k*R2)/R2-2*cos(k*l1)*exp(-i*k*R0)/R0);
    return Ez;
}
```

Comment: Читайте про `std::complex`.

Comment: В С++14 вроде появился специальный оператор `operator""i`. Т.е. мнимую единицу можно писать просто как `1i`

Comment: Или использовать `<complex>`, или головой и руками поработать и записать отдельно действительную и отдельно мнимую части...